# modeling of sum of sinusoidal components in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

let us consider following model,
[image]

let us suppose that we have sum of 4 sinusoidal component  with sampling frequency 100, that means sampling period is ts=0.01;but how can i  do in simulink? could you please help me?what i need is to estimate power spectrum of signal generated by 4 sinusoidal components  with 4  frequency  and sampling frequency 100,how can i do that?  let us take example of  configuration of one sinusoidal component

[image]

and also  structure of  periodogram block

[image]

am i doing everything correctly?

UPDATED :

error message  is that

Error in 'sum_of_signal/Periodogram/Periodogram - Frame Period To Sample Time/Error if Continuous Sample Time/Check Signal Attributes': All sample times for this block must be discrete.
Continuous sample time is not allowed.
Component: Simulink | Category: Block error

An error occurred while propagating numeric type real from 'sum_of_signal/Periodogram/Periodogram - Frame Period To Sample Time/Error if Continuous Sample Time/In1', output port 1.
Component: Simulink | Category: Block error

update : see please

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `Sample Time` is not correctly setted in the `Sine Wave` blocks: their sample time are setted to `0` and as you can see in the `Periodogram` block mask it will inherit that (wrong) sample time and will produce that error. So set the correct sample time (`0.01` s) in the `Sine Wave` blocks and it will work.

PS: I suggest the `Spectrum Analyzer` block to see the spectrum out of the `Periodogram` block

Comment: how can i correctly  set sampling time? also spectrum analyzer after periodogram or instead of periodgram?

Comment: i have added  spectrum analyzer,but no result

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VeDLv.png) you can set the sample time in the last option. Connect the `Spectrum Analyzer` block after the `Periodogram` block as a `Scope`(instead of a `Scope`). It allows you to see the spectrum in the frequency domain.

Comment: I have seen it. Were it not your aim ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the `Periodogram` block? Try directly the `Power Spectral Density` block. You can find it in the `Simulink Extras`

Comment: i need to use periodogram method

Comment: Ok. Add a `Buffer` block before `Periodogram` block and set the FFT length as `Output buffer size`. In the `Periodogram` block set just `1` as `Number of spectral averages` if you don't want to use the Welch's method. Connect the output of the `Periodogram` block to a `Vector Scope` block and set its properties (Frequency Domain, X-limits, Y-limits, decibel/magnetude, etc.)

Comment: i have got this error : Model 'sum_of_signal' has been configured to record logged data for inspection. Based on the current data logging settings, no data will be recorded. To stop the running simulation and setup the model to log data, select the stop button on the toolbar. To disable recording, deselect the record button on the toolbar. For additional information, see help for configuring data logging.

Comment: i have to delete this question no help

Comment: I believe you have not correctly setted the model. I have tried it and it works. You can find it [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31341375/try_model_sine.slx). Add the other Sine wave, frequencies, amplitude, etc how is your aim